# What is the Regular Expression to match the space between two words (lower case and upper case)

Tags: javascript, regex, google-sheets

I have a dataset in google sheets where the "name" field looks like this:

```
Stephen & Sally Fitzpatrick
```

I am trying to figure out the Regular expression to find the space between "Sally Fitzpatrick" so I can split it into Name and Last Name. That way Stephen & Sally remain in the name field and Fitzpatrick becomes the last name.

But the extent of the question is simply to find that space, not split it.

I believe it is a fairly new compiler, so \s, \b, \w are supported.

Comment: Matching names is not a trivial thing because there are far more combinations of names that you are considering. I guess you were thinking something like `[a-z] [A-Z]`, but that would fall apart the first time you meet a `von Braun`

Comment: Yeah good point @MattBurland

Comment: As Matt said, parsing name strings is not simple, there are many different forms. How about Sally Ann, Sarah Jane and Sue Saxe-Coburg and Gotha? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're probably looking for is something similar to `/(\S+\s\&\s\S+)(\s)(\S+)/`.

Breaking this down:

- Grab the first string, space, ampersand and space, along with the second string, and group all of that as the first group
- Grab the space in between `Sally` and `Fitzpatrick` and consider it a group
- Grab the third string by itself, and consider it a group

This can be seen in the following:

```js
let string = 'Stephen & Sally Fitzpatrick';
console.log(string.split(/(\S+\s\&\s\S+)(\s)(\S+)/).filter(Boolean));
```

Note that this will match all three components; you can exclude the ones you don't want by affixing `?:` just inside of the brackets. Doing this to the first and third set will **only** yield the relevant space:

```js
let string = 'Stephen & Sally Fitzpatrick';
console.log(string.split(/(?:\S+\s\&\s\S+)(\s)(?:\S+)/).filter(Boolean));
```

Comment: Thanks. That was it!

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution using lookarounds:

```
/(?<=[A-Za-z])\s(?=[A-Za-z])/.exec('Stephen & Sally Fitzpatrick')

// -> [" ", index: 15, input: "Stephen & Sally Fitzpatrick", groups: undefined]
```

```js
const [first, last] = 'Stephen & Sally Fitzpatrick'.split(/(?<=[A-Za-z]) (?=[A-Za-z])/);

console.log(`first: ${first}, last: ${last}`);
```

Check [lookbehind proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind).